# No matching distribution found for discord-ext-bot==1.0.1

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, discord, discord.py, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to deploy my discord bot to AWS.
The error occurs from the requirements.txt file which was created automatically using pip freeze

I have installed pycord manually from the console coz of the same fail before, but the failure still exists.
I am using pycord coz I need to use the slash commands. (discord.py worked fine on AWS previously but it has no slash commands)

The bot works perfectly fine when I run directly from my PC.

```
[stdout]Collecting discord==1.7.3
[stdout] Using cached discord-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
[stderr]ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.0.7 Requires-Python >=3.8.1; 0.0.8 Requires-Python >=3.8.1; 0.0.9 Requires-Python >=3.8.1; 0.0.9rc1 Requires-Python >=3.8.1; 1.0.0 Requires-Python >=3.8.1; 1.0.1 Requires-Python >=3.8.1
[stderr]ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord-ext-bot==1.0.1 (from versions: none)
[stderr]ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord-ext-bot==1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install py-cord -U
```

or

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord
```

(git required for the second method)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).